# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discusión, site-evaluation

We all love [Spanish Language Stack Exchange](http://spanish.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Does "No tengo sueño" really have these two quite different meanings?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8374/does-no-tengo-sue%c3%b1o-really-have-these-two-quite-different-meanings)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Should I eat my apple? Usage of the preposition "en"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8297/should-i-eat-my-apple-usage-of-the-preposition-en)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- ["Se me ha pasado de volada" - ¿Mal dicho?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8287/se-ma-ha-pasado-de-volada-mal-dicho)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Use of em dash in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8442/use-of-em-dash-in-spanish)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Why is this singular event spoken/written as if it were plural in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/why-is-this-singular-event-spoken-written-as-if-it-were-plural-in-spanish)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How is "se" used in the context of passive voice?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8324/how-is-se-used-in-the-context-of-passive-voice)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Proper translation of Epicaricacy?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8462/proper-translation-of-epicaricacy)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Why would "water" not be translated?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8278/why-would-water-not-be-translated)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [usage of "su" (the pronoun)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8279/usage-of-su-the-pronoun)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [When the Moors conquered Spain did Spaniards already speak Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8400/when-the-moors-conquered-spain-did-spaniards-already-speak-spanish)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 5)

---